# QGIS / Python differences in result

Tags: qgis, python, landsat-7

I am working on a script that automatically calculates something for me. To be sure, I checked the result of the calculation with QGIS. Here are the statistics:

STATISTICS PYTHON-CODE:

```
MAXIMUM = 0.9896427989006
MEAN = -0.21678630311319
MINIMUM = -0.69955635070801
STDDEV = 0.24564237169808
```

STATISTICS QGIS:

```
MAXIMUM = 1
MEAN = -0.4204168536468
MINIMUM = -0.69955635070801
STDDEV = 0.17747956958404
```

I created my script based on this: https://gist.github.com/jgomezdans/1336359. Here it is:

```
def filter2 (band2, band5):
    ds2 = gdal.Open(band2)
    data2 = ds2.ReadAsArray()
    ds5 = gdal.Open(band5)
    data5 = ds5.ReadAsArray()
    check = np.logical_and(data2 > 0, data5 > 0)
    filter2 = np.where(check, (data2 - data5) / (data2  + data5), 0)
    return filter2
```

In QGIS I used the raster calculator:

```
(band2 - band5) / (band2 +  band5)
```

Bands 2 and 5 originate from a landsat 7 image and are converted to reflectance values (so no DN).

I think I am doing something wrong with the check and np.where lines but when I just calculate the ratio in the script as:

```
filter2 = (data2 - data5) / (data2 + data5)
```

the answer is NaN.

I am not sure if I should worry about the differences in the statistics, but I think I should. And also, I'd like to know why I get NaN when I do not use the check.

Comment: You didn't try filtering the Landsat image in QGIS? (i.e., B2 > 0, B5 > 0) ? How are the statistics after that. Are there  negative values in the layers?

Comment: I tried, but it doesn't make a difference

Comment: To be sure, you should test it on something where you know the result. Construct a small raster with known values where you can hand-compute the result you want. Then test. For all you know, your QGIS *and* python calculations could both be wrong!